# How to set state of variable within input group on click?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

## Problem

I want to set a number for the variable `focus` that marks the last touched input field (`0` for false and `1` for true).

Currently this is working for single input fields but not for input groups within my Vue.js view.

## Data source

Here you can see the array with the `focus` variable in the console of Chrome inspector:

```
tracking Event [{…}]
 0:
  formData: Array(15)
   0: {name: "selectedProcess", value: "example", focus: 0, type: "radio"}
   1: {name: "gender", value: "F", focus: 0, type: "radio"}
   2: {name: "firstname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
   3: {name: "lastname", value: "filled_out", focus: 1, type: "input"}
   4: {name: "birthday", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
   5: {name: "street", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
   6: {name: "streetNo", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
   7: {name: "zip", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
   8: {name: "city", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
   9: {name: "countryKey", value: "de", focus: 0, type: "select"}
   10: {name: "email", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
   11: {name: "actioncode", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
   12: {name: "selectedCard", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "radio"}
   13: {name: "allowDataUsage", value: "unchecked", focus: 0, type: "checkbox"}
   14: {name: "cardNumber", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "input"}
   length: 15
  __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

As you can see: array item [3] `lastname` was touched last and its focus was successfully registered as `1`.

This behaviour is not working for all input fields on the registry form.

Some inputs (like `lastname`) are single input fields. Others like street, zip, ... and birthday, birthmonths, ... are within an input group component.

Example: the birthday group component holds inputs for day, month and birthyear.

## Implementation of focus

Currently, I have implemented the use of focus like this:

```
function formatTracking(data) {
  let { name, value, focus, type, isSensible } = data;

  if (isBrowser) {
    let currentElements = document.querySelector(`input[data-identity="${name}"]`);

    if (!currentElements) {
      currentElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`[data-identity="${name}"] input`));
    } else {
      currentElements = [currentElements];
    }

    focus = 0;
    for (let index in currentElements) {
      focus = currentElements[index] === document.activeElement ? 1 : 0;

      if (focus) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

...

}
```

## How form is pushed to data layer (array)

```
const trackingData = [
    {
      name: 'selectedProcess',
      value: selectedProcess ? selectedProcess.value : null,
      type: 'radio'
    },
    { name: 'gender', value: account.genderKey, type: 'radio' },
    {
      name: 'firstname',
      value: account.firstName,
      type: 'input',
      isSensible: true
    },
    {
      name: 'lastname',
      value: account.lastName,
      type: 'input',
      isSensible: true
    },
    {
      name: 'birthday',
      value: hasInterface(account.birthday, {
        day: isValidString,
        month: isValidString,
        year: isValidString
      })
        ? account.birthday
        : null,
      type: 'input',
      isSensible: true
    },
    {
      name: 'street',
      value: account.address.street,
      type: 'input',
      isSensible: true
    },
    {
      name: 'streetNo',
      value: account.address.streetNo,
      type: 'input',
      isSensible: true
    },

...
]
```

I expect to see focus `1` on any input that was touched last. This is not working for birthday input group and address input group.

I assume the function `formTracking` which sets `focus` from `0` to `1` is not correct.

Comment: how  formatTracking(data) is called?

Comment: Is it a viable option for you to track the activeElement with `focus`/`blur` events on document and record the last active item in a variable?

Comment: @A1rPun: yes sure, that would be a viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to track the active element.

```
function updateActiveElement() {
  const currentActiveElement = document.activeElement;
  if (lastActiveElement !== currentActiveElement)
    lastActiveElement = currentActiveElement;
}

let lastActiveElement = document.activeElement;
window.addEventListener('focus', updateActiveElement);
window.addEventListener('blur', updateActiveElement);
```

When you need to last active element just check the `lastActiveElement` variable.

If you only want to track inputs you can add a check in the `updateActiveElement()` function.